# How to add EMPTY col on the right in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have a layout like this on lg screen =>

```
|   col 6   | | EMPTY col 6 |
|   col 6   | |    col 6    |
```

and this on small screen

I want to have a layout like this on <lg screen (no empty) =>

```
|   col 12   | 
|   col 12   | 
|   col 12   |
```

but I don't get how to do it correctly with the `offset`

I CAN'T use different row, cause it would break the layout on MOBILE. Check the snippet in **full screen**

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          Column
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

if I try with offset on the middle row in large, it just add a offset of 12 !

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-6 col-12">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          Column
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

the only way I found is this, but I am sure there is better ?

if I try with offset on the middle row in large, it just add a offset of 12 !

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          Column
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-flex">
          EMPTY COL 
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-6 col-12">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          Column
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add extra css if you are using bootstrap 3 like below example.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <style>
      .row-flex {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
    
      .w-100 {
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-flex">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
         Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque.
        </div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque.
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:pink;">
          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is the same hack but using w-100,

Comment: so what you want

Answer (score 0):

here a version you asked. In Bootstrap 3 there is no flex-box.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="visible-lg-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
          Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
          Column
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```